# Can I put one check on a Lexial element instead for on a number of parser rules?

Tags: antlr4

I,m trying to use antlr4 with the [IDL.g4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/idl) grammar, to implement some checks that our idl-files shall follow. One rule is about names. The rule are like:

- ID contains only letters, digits and signle underscores,
- ID begin with a letter,
- ID end with a letter or digit.
- ID is not a reserved Word in ADA, C, C++, Java, IDL

One way to do this check is to write a function that check a string for these properties and call it in the *exit listeners* for every rule that has an ID. E.g(refering to IDL.g4) in `exitConst_decl()`, `exitInit_decl()`, `exitSimple_declarator()` and a lot of more places. Maybe that is the correct way to do it. But I was thinking about putting that check directly on the lexical element `ID`. But don't know how to do that, or if it is possible at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validating this type of constraint in the lexer would make it significantly more difficult to provide usable error messages for invalid identifiers. However, you can create a new parser rule `identifier`, and replace all references to `ID` in various parser rules to reference `identifier` instead.

```
identifier
  : ID
  ;
```

You can then place your identifier validation logic inside of the single method `enterIdentifier` instead of all of the various rules that currently reference `ID`.